# Celery Result Backend on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I've gone through the docs multiple times but haven't been able to figure out as to how should we configure the filesystem backend on Windows machine. 
i.e if I have a directory structure like this `C:\Users\A\B\C` and I specify `backend=file://C:\\Users\\A\\B\\C\\`, I get a NoneType Error.

While on Linux it was as easy as `file:///var/celery/results/`

I've been stuck on this for hours now. Any clue would be really helpful?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on Windows 10 (Celery 4.2.1). Though I'm not 100% sure from your question whether you want to use the filesystem as your message broker or your result backend:

```
app = Celery('app')
app.conf.update({
    'broker_url': 'filesystem://',
    'broker_transport_options': {
        'data_folder_in': '/broker/out',
        'data_folder_out': '/broker/out',
        'data_folder_processed': '/broker/processed'
    },
    'result_backend': 'file:///broker/results',
    'result_persistent': True
```

})

Comment: Hey Bjoern, I appreciate your answer but the snippet you shared is for `broker` and I'm concerned about the `backend`. I've gone through the code and apparently `file:///` is hardcoded in the filesystem.py file in the project. Check this out https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/backends/filesystem.py#L61

Comment: I've added `'result_backend': 'file:///broker/results'``` and `'result_persistent': True`. Does that work for you?

Comment: If I do something like `file:///D:\results`, where D is the drive label on Windows and results folder is accessible to python script, it raises an `OSError` because the filename which open method uses is `/D:\\results\\.abc-xxx-xxx-xxx`. Does it work for you?
Moreover, I'm not using the windows subsystem as well. It might be you're running this under linux, maybe?

Comment: I'm definitely running on Windows. However, sounds like the underlying issue that you need to know the UNC path for your D drive. Is that D drive a local or a network drive?

Comment: Man. Thanks alot! You're a savior.
Using the UNC path I was able to get it working. Kudos!

Answer (score 3):

Just add one cent.

Celery backends code keep the first '/' when stripping the path, so you have to pass in a UNC. https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/backends/filesystem.py

On windows, UNC path is like "//?/c:/xxx". So I use below config string for the backend

YOUR_PATH="D:\path\on\windows\"

broker_url = 'file:////?/%s' % (YOUR_PATH.replace('\','/'))

Comment: The adjustment that worked for me:
YOUR_PATH="C:\\Users"
win_path = 'file:////?/%s' % (YOUR_PATH.replace('\\','/'))

Thanks for your initial input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UNC path (like using SMB file share or something), you may need to replace the backslash `\` with slash `/` character.

In my case, I have to write the setting as follows (assume using new lowercase settings), so the Celery library can parse it correctly in Windows environment.

```py
# celeryconfig.py
broker_url = 'filesystem:////<hostname>/<sharename>/broker/messages'
broker_transport_options = {
    'data_folder_in': '//<hostname>/<sharename>/broker/out',
    'data_folder_out': '//<hostname>/synoshare/broker/out',
    'data_folder_processed': '//<hostname>/<sharename>/broker/processed'
}
result_backend = 'file:////weidavm.syno/<sharename>/broker/results'
result_persistent = True
```

Tested under Windows 10, Python 3.6 and Celery 4.x.